# BitSet vs. raw bitwise manipulation performance

Tags: java

How does BitSet performance compare vs. raw manipulation of say, long values?

Comment: Really? It's not acceptable to ask if someone has already done this?

Comment: If you are going to profile, I would stick to `int[]` instead of `long[]`, because JVMs are not guaranteed to perform operations on `long`s atomically.

Comment: I would also say that if you know that your bitset size is going to be small enough -- say 128 bits or something like that, then you can avoid the array indirection and squeeze out performance. But it strikes me that the old premature optimization evil thing is in full force here...

Comment: @Dilum it's ironic that you would in one post say to use `int[]` instead of `long[]` to get atomic operation, and then in the next warn about premature optimization...

Comment: @Kevin The performance of both will be blazing fast. BitSet is already written for you. The choice is obvious, to me. Also, whenever I'm tempted to use a BitSet, I have to ask myself "What am I managing that I require so many flags that I'm willing to lose referential integrity to keep them all in my object?" Sets of bits are clunky and easy to... well... screw up.

Comment: I currently have bitwise operations but it imposes artificial limits (only 64 of x allowed...). I'd like to switch to bitset as long as performance isn't poor.

Comment: @Kevin what kind of data are you storing in the bitset?

Comment: It's a filter mask of input data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://imagenious.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/java-bitset-vs-primitive/

First result from googling "java bitset performance"

For unbounded sets of bits, however, BitSet has obvious advantages.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see this in my initial googling.